# Adding REST endpoints for custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, rest, custom-post-type

I find the documentation for the new WordPress REST API (v2) very inadequate and/or incomplete. I have a plugin which defines custom post types and I would like to use the REST API for its intended purpose. I've tried to follow the example in the documentation, but when I try the relevant URL (http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/prsp/v1/attributes) I get a "rest_no_route" response.

My custom post types do show up on the response for "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types" however.

Can anyone comment?

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => 'prsp-top-level-handle',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'prsp-attribute', 'with_front' => FALSE),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    ...
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller'
); 
register_post_type('prsp-attribute', $args);
```

...

```
    $this->admin = new ProspectAdmin($this->get_version());

    $this->loader->add_action('admin_init', $this->admin, 'do_prsp_init', null, null);

    $this->loader->add_action('admin_menu', $this->admin, 'add_prsp_menus', null, null);

    $this->loader->add_action('rest_api_init', $this->admin, 'add_rest_api', null, null);
```

...

```
public function rest_get_attributes()
{
    return 'rest_get_attributes()'; // Temporary test for success
} // rest_get_attributes()

public function add_rest_api()
{
    register_rest_route('prsp/v1', '/attributes', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array($this, 'rest_get_attributes')
        ));
    register_rest_route('prsp/v1', '/attribute/(?P<id>\w+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array($this, 'rest_get_attribute')
        ));
} // add_rest_api()
```

And, where is the explanation of the format for the second parameter of register_rest_route()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL should be `http://example.com/wp-json/prsp/v1/attributes`.

You may list the existing routes and endpoints via GET `http://example.com/wp-json` (or GET `http://example.com/wp-json/prsp/v1`).

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please accept the answer, so we both get our points.

Comment: Do you know where is the format for the second parameter explained?  I need to pass multiple parameters to one of my functions, and I see no explanation of delimiters or anything relating to multiple parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I've figured out through an educated guess.  Here's an example of one I added:    '/records/(?P<id>[\w\-]+)&(?P<from>\d+)&(?P<count>\d+)'